# Find the unknown $n$

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices (with 2013 rows and columns) such that
$A^9$ = $1$ and $ABA^{-1}$ = $B^2$, then prove that there exists a natural number
$n$ such that $B^n = 1$. Find the smallest such $n$.

Comment: Note that $AB^2A^{-1} = (ABA^{-1})^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $AB = B^2A$, from which it immediately follows that $AB^n = B^{2n}A$. Thus, it can be shown by induction that $A^n B = B^{2^n}A^n$.

Now consider $B = A^9 B = B^{2^9}A^9 = B^{2^9}$, since $B$ is invertible this means that $B^{2^9-1} = I$. Hence such an $n$ is $2^9-1 = 511$

The smallest such $n$ must now divide $511$, hence $n\in\{1,7,73,511\}$.